# How does the Calendar app on Windows Phone update its live tile even with the battery saver on?

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar, windows-phone, live-tile, battery-saver

I am trying to develop a simple calendar app with a live tile but in battery saver mode the background agent won't run and I can't have the live tile updated with the current day and day of week.

I noticed that the Calendar (1st party app) does not suffer from this problem even in Battery Saver mode.

Does it get special attention / capabilities being a first party app or there is some trick that I don't know (yet)?

Comment: I would assume this is a limitation for 3rd party apps. I know that if I turn on *my* battery saver, I don't want my apps to be updating (as often).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in (or system) apps are not restrained in the same way that 3rd party apps are. There are many examples of this on Windows Phone but two visible ones are...

- The calendar app updating its Live Tile even when Battery Saver is turned on (which you noted).
- The People Hub Live Tile which has many small tiles which rotate in sequence - as developers, we don't have access to that Live Tile Template.
- The Photos Hub Live Tile displays photos using a panning animation - also not available to developers.

As there is no 'fix' if your `PeriodicTask` doesn't run as expected, you'll simply have to update the tile when your app runs as well as checking the status of the `PeriodicTask` each time.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected this but I thought it's better to ask. My work-around has been to discreetly write the day of the rendering of the tile on the tile (Like, "Fri, 2" if the tile was generated on 2nd of August). This however led me to WriteableBitmapEx which must be run on the UI thread and had to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke from the Background Agent. This final bit sucks because I'm stealing UI juice from the user... Maybe this will be the subject of a future question..

Comment: iOS is similar, the system apps can do special things 3rd party apps cannot - the calendar and clock app (in iOS 7) can update their icons yet *no* other app can. As for your 2nd question, I'll simply say that dispatching to the UI thread in a Background Agent doesn't matter much, I wouldn't worry. Keeping under the memory limit is always the problem, especially on WP7.